# Pandas many-to-many indexing/grouping

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have 2 series, both multiindexed, similar to s1 and s2 below:

```py
s1 = pd.Series({(x,y):x*y for x in range(4) for y in range(4)})
s2 = pd.Series({('a',0):0,('a',1):2,('a',2):3,('b',0):0,('b',1):3})
```

I want to use the values of s2 to select values from the first level of s1, resulting in a series like the following:

```py
a  0  0    0
      1    0
      2    0
      3    0
   2  0    0
      1    2
      2    4
      3    6
b  1  0    0
      1    1
      2    2
      3    3
   3  0    0
      1    3
      2    6
      3    9
dtype: int64
```

The plan is to use this for groupby operations, for each entry in s2, I want to take the max from s1 (also grouping by the level 1 of s1's index), then add together the corresponding maxima after grouping again by level 1.

Currently, the best solution I've come up with is `s3 = pd.concat({idx:s1.loc[s2.loc[idx]] for idx in s2.index.get_level_values(0)})`, but this feels too roundabout to be the best/most canonical solution to the problem. Is there a neater solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Create `DataFrame`s and join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with aggregate `max`:

```
s3 = (s2.reset_index()
        .merge(s1.reset_index(), left_on=0, right_on='level_1')
        .groupby(['level_0_x','0_x','level_0_y'])['0_y']
        .max()
        .rename(None)
        .rename_axis([None, None, None]))
print (s3)
a  0  0    0
      1    0
      2    0
      3    0
   2  0    0
      1    2
      2    4
      3    6
   3  0    0
      1    3
      2    6
      3    9
b  0  0    0
      1    0
      2    0
      3    0
   3  0    0
      1    3
      2    6
      3    9
dtype: int64
```

Your solution got different ouput like in question:

```
s3 = pd.concat({idx:s1.loc[s2.loc[idx]] for idx in s2.index.get_level_values(0)})
print (s3)
a  0  0    0
      1    0
      2    0
      3    0
   2  0    0
      1    2
      2    4
      3    6
   3  0    0
      1    3
      2    6
      3    9
b  0  0    0
      1    0
      2    0
      3    0
   3  0    0
      1    3
      2    6
      3    9
dtype: int64
```